# Dockerfile: reference file like an alias instead of Docker ADD?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My project has the following structure:

project

- app (directory with my application code)
- images (directory with docker images pre builds)
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- other files

When I run `docker-compose up -d` I would like my `backend` container to mirror the host `app` folder to container `/var/www/app` so any change I make in app in directly reflected within the docker container and therefore make my development easy.

At the moment I use this in my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM backend
ADD ./app /var/www/app/
EXPOSE 8000
```

which is basically copying files but I need to rebuild for every change :((

I created volume `APP_DATA_DIR=/var/www/app/public/data` for persisting user data but that will be for production use only.

For development is it possible to "ALIAS" (reference to file instead of copy) instead of ADD ?

docker-compose is

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: serverBuild
    restart: always
    build: ./
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "app_data:${APP_DATA_DIR}"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - app_network

  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: "mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION}"
    restart: 'always'
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - "db_data:${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}"
      - "db_logs:${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app_network

volumes:
  app_data:
  db_data:
  db_logs:

networks:
  app_network:
```

.env

```
MARIADB_VERSION=latest
APP_DATA_DIR=/var/www/app/public/data
MARIADB_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mysql
MARIADB_LOG_DIR=/var/logs/mysql
MYSQL_DATABASE=app
MYSQL_USER=app
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
SQL_INIT=./database/dev
```

Comment: "*For development is it possible to ALIAS instead of ADD ?*" - What do you mean by this? There is no `ALIAS` that I know of in the docker jargon. Please [edit] the post and clarify.

Comment: @Turing85 i mean a reference, edited the question

Comment: You can do day-to-day development without Docker (and without Docker's filesystem isolation), and use Docker for integration testing and deployment.  You can also run just the database in Docker but not the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply declare a volume in `docker-compose.yml` inside the service, a concept you are using already. Simply do `./app:/var/www/app/`

I would also like to advise you to use [`COPY` instead of `ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) when copying files.

I don't know what you mean with `For development is it possible to ALIAS instead of ADD ?` so I can't help you there unless you clarify that point but this should make what you want.

Comment: I mean by alias that it is a reference to the file instead of hard copy. if I create `./app:/var/www/app/` would that interfere with my `APP_DATA_DIR=/var/www/app/public/data` effectively creating a volume inside a volume ?

Comment: I have never tried to do that so I can't be sure but I don't think it will be an issue (it's better if you test it.) But it's probably not a good idea to use the same Dockerfile/Docker-compose/.env/same configurations for both development and production (each case is a case but I would think about it again and search on the internet about the topic.)